# java: fully controlled input on JTextField

Tags: java, textinput, jtextfield

I want to have a `JTextField` (or another text-like input which supports focus and a cursor -- or maybe I should code my own?) where I want to have full control over the immediate input. I.e. I want to ignore most inputs and handle the rest specifically. It seems that `JFormattedTextField` is not what I want because it does the verification not on the immediate input but when the focus is lost.

I tried to add a key listener but it's a bit non-obvious how I should use it. It seems I can catch up events like cursor changes (via keys) or copy/paste (via key-shortcuts) in `keyPressed` and I can catch all normal key input in `keyTyped`. I am not sure how I can catch cursor changes or copy/paste made via mouse (for some reason, right click does not work anyway, so copy/paste via mouse in the context menu seems not possible but I am not sure if that might be a different issue or if it should work and just does not for some reason).

I basically want something like the following handler:

```
interface InputHandler {
   void addStringAt(int pos, String s);
   void deleteSubString(int pos, int len);
   void setFocusTo(int pos);
}
```

And it should be absolutely impossible for the user to get any stuff onto the textbox which are not going through this handler.

Right now, it seems like I have to take care about a lot of specific cases (like on some architectures, there may be some context menu where they could copy/paste or input something, handle all mouse events manually, etc).

Or the other way, which also involves a lot of special handlings: To recode such input field myself. This still seems saver because I can know for sure that there are no tricky methods how the user could bypass the handler (and I really must know that for sure). Btw., how would I do this? I thought of extending a `JLabel`. How can I extend it so that it can get a focus?

I wonder how you would implement something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a [`DocumentFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html). A couple of existing questions that will help with this:

- [Cut and Paste in JTextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206525/cut-and-paste-in-jtextarea)
- [Help on writing your own javax.swing.text.Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516638/help-on-writing-your-own-javax-swing-text-document)